# Is the set $A=\{x\in l_p :x_n \in \mathbb Q\}$ countable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, lp-spaces, separable-spaces, second-countable

Is the set $A=\{x\in \it l_p :x_n \in \mathbb Q\}$ countable?If yes,then I can show that $l_p$ space is separable with resepect to the metric $d(x,y)=(\sum _nx_n^p)^{1/p}$.

Comment: The answers given are correct - the set $A$ is not countable. However, $\ell^p$ is separable with respect to this metric. To see this, note that $c_{00} \subseteq \ell^p$ for and that $\overline{c_{00}} = c_0$, which contains $\ell^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the set is not countable: *finite* products of countable are countable, countable such products are not. Even $2^\mathbb{N}$ is not (a countable product of two point sets). But take those sequences (rational ones) that are $0$ after some index and try to show *that* set is countable and dense.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Pick your favourite element $x \in l_p$ with $x_n \in \mathbb Q$ and $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n$.

For each subset $B \subset \mathbb N$ define 
$$y_B(n)= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
x_n & \mbox{ if } n \in B \\
0 & \mbox{ if } n\notin B
\end{array}
\right.$$

Show that $B \to y_B$ defines a one to one function from $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ to $A$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not. For any subset $A $ of $\mathbb N$ define $x_n= 2^{-n}$ if $n \in A$ and $0$ otherwise. This given an element of your set and the map $A \to x$ is one-to-one.